# how can I calculate the entropy of individual pixels

Tags: image, matlab, entropy

How can I calculate the `entropy` of individual pixels? The function entropy of matlab calculates the entropy of an image. I want to calculate the entropy of every pixel

Comment: I would strongly recommend against it. You need a distribution in order to measure entropy. 3x3 pixels are too few to estimate a distribution...

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551422/how-can-i-calculate-the-entropy-of-individual-pixels#comment27293372_18551422), it is meaningless to ask the entropy of a **single** pixel.

Having said that, you might want to look at [`entropyfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropyfilt.html) - measuring the entropy of a **region** around a pixel.

Comment: you are right, I used entropyfilt but i could not got expected result, I want to write  one function in order to calculate   entropy of windows 32*32  in image and its output should be equal of size input image.